# __metaclass__ not worked when create class with type("Test", (Base,), {'__metaclass__':Meta, ...})

Tags: python, metaclass

```
cls = type("Test", (Base,), {"__metaclass__": Meta, "a": 1, ...})
```

I want to make some check for the attrs in the 3rd argument with Meta class, but this seem not worked, is there any other method?

Comment: You should provide an MCVE https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Meta`-class is a subclass of `type`. So creating a type of a metaclass is calling the meta class:

```
cls = Meta("Test", (Base,), {"a": 1, ...})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create your `Test` class by calling the `Meta` (a.k.a. `type.__class__.__new__(Meta, "Test", (Base,), {"__metaclass__": Meta, "a": 1})`.

If you have a dictionary with possible `__metaclass__`, you can use the following code:

```
members = {"__metaclass__": Meta, "a": 1, ...}  
metaclass = members.pop('__metaclass__', type)
cls = metaclass("Test", (Base,), members)
```